# Is there any reason to keep the WCF interface in a separate file?

Tags: wcf, interface

Just personal style, I guess, but I hate having 2 files for my WCF Services.  I tend to like to copy/paste the interface into the .cs file so that I only have to deal with a single file.

Any dangers in doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not dangers per se - but there are times when it is very useful to have a separate assembly with your service, operation and data contracts (just the contracts, the interfaces, basically) - when you need to share those between the server and the client side.

There's really no point in sharing the whole service implementation code (the actual service class, that implements the service interface), with the client.

Plus: if you have your interfaces in a separate file (and possibly assembly), it makes it easier to write unit tests, especially if you want to mock a service. Gets a bit messy if you mix interface and class into a single file.

So I consider it a useful and helpful best practice to have separate files for interfaces and implementations (actually: always one class per file only), and to put all service- and data contracts (and fault contracts) into a separate assembly.

Comment: Agree, +1 for you, just a little addition: One Class One file. don't your think it applies here too in some way?

Comment: Thanks!  That makes a lot of sense, and it seems clean.  I like it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I like to go beyond two files, and have two separate projects.  One project holds the interface definition.  The primary value is for integration testing.  I like to make a third project with a WCF client.  That client accesses the interface in the "shared" assembly.

Remember the [mantra of Testivus](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=203994): "When writing the (production) code, think of the test; When writing the test, think of the code."